# Haskell: http-wget hangs my program in windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cygwin, wget

I've tried this on two computers.  Here are my steps:

1. install wget on cygwin
2. `cabal install http-wget`
3. upgrade my PATH environment variable to include C:\cygwin\bin
4. open WinGHCi and type this:

From prompt:

```
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m + Network.HTTP.Wget
Prelude Network.HTTP.Wget> wget "http://www.google.com" [] []
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package Win32-2.2.2.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.1.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.1.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package failure-0.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.2.2.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package http-wget-0.6.2.3 ... linking ... done.
```

Nothing else happens after this line.  The command doesn't complete.  It just hangs forever.  I'm very new to Haskell and don't know how to debug this issue.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.2
```

I've tried the wget command in the cygwin prompt and it works as expected.

This works from WinGHCi:

```
let getGoogle = do (_, Just hout, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "wget" ["-q", "www.google.com", "-O", "-"]){ std_out = CreatePipe }; hGetContents hout
```

I got that from IRC from a gentleman named mcstar

Comment: Does it work when you compile your program with ghc compiler and run the binary instead of running it from ghci interpreter?

Comment: @Rotsor: I `ghc --make prog.hs` and then did `./prog.exe` in cygwin.  It hanged the same way.

Comment: The http-wget package was orphaned and marked deprecated in 2012: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-wget -- the only answer is "don't use it."